# RecyclerView Checkbox Registering CheckedChanged Event Via Interface Getting IllegalStateException Error

Tags: java, android, event-handling, android-recyclerview

I have been trying to register `checkedchangeevent` on a recyclerview item via interface so i could access that event in my activity. You can see the example code below. The problem is i cannot call notifyitemchanged  in activity because i get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling`. **However, i was able to register checkedchangevent without using interfaces** ***but i need interface version of it***

**My interface**

```
public void setItemClickCallBack(final ItemClickCallBack itemCall){
        this.itemCall = itemCall;
}
public interface ItemClickCallBack{
    void setOnRootClick(int pos);
    void setCheckChangeClick(int pos);
}
```

**My View Holder**

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements  View.OnClickListener, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

    private TextView tv1;
    private TextView tv2;
    private CheckBox cb;
    private View rootLayout;

    private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        rootLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
        tv1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        cb = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb);

        rootLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId() == R.id.rootLayout)
            itemCall.setOnRootClick(getAdapterPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(buttonView.getId() == R.id.cb)
            itemCall.setCheckChangeClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

**My OnBind**

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final News n = newsData.get(position);

    holder.tv1.setText(n.getText());

    if(n.isStatus())
        holder.tv2.setText("Basıldı ve tickli");
    else
        holder.tv2.setText("Basıldı ve ticksiz");
    holder.cb.setChecked(n.isStatus());
}
```

**My Activity**

```
@Override
public void setCheckChangeClick(int pos) {
    News n = newsData.get(pos);
    if(n.isStatus())
        n.setStatus(false);
    else
        n.setStatus(true);

    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemChanged(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `checkedchangelistener` on `OnBind` method and registering via a function in ViewHolder class fixed the problem

```
**OnBind**

 holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
 holder.cb.setChecked(n.isStatus());
 holder.registerCheckedChangeListener();

**ViewHolder**

 private void registerCheckedChangeListener(){
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
  }
```